# Sliding puzzle jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sliding

I'm trying to solve the sliding problem(3*3 grid) through jquery.

In my HTML file I have 8 li's(9th empty).

```
    <ul class="Puzzle">
        <li class="Box Box1">1</li>
        <li class="Box Box2">2</li>
        <li class="Box Box3">3</li>
        <li class="Box Box4">4</li>
        <li class="Box Box5">5</li>
        <li class="Box Box6">6</li>
        <li class="Box Box7">7</li>
        <li class="Box Box8">8</li>
    </ul>
```

I want to access these li's in my js(javascript file) through jQuery,so that I can implement the sliding effect. 
I tried to convert them into arrays through jQuery.map() function but it didn't work

```
    var liclass = $('Puzzle li').map(function(i,n){
            return $(n).attr('class');
        }).get().join(',');
```

Can someone please tell me how can I convert them into arrays and use them in my js file.

Thanks

Comment: im not quite sure want your final goal is, this could help to provide better information, do you want to implement a slideshow?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to get a collection of those `li`s (wrapped as jQuery objects) would be

```
var lis = $('.Puzzle li')
```

You were missing the `.` - jQuery class name selectors should start with a period (as in CSS).

If you need an array holding the numbers in these `li`s, that should be

```
var arr = $('.Puzzle li').map(function() {
    $(this).text();
}).get();
```

See this (console):

```js
var lis = $('.Puzzle li');
var arr = lis.map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Puzzle">
  <li class="Box Box1">1</li>
  <li class="Box Box2">2</li>
  <li class="Box Box3">3</li>
  <li class="Box Box4">4</li>
  <li class="Box Box5">5</li>
  <li class="Box Box6">6</li>
  <li class="Box Box7">7</li>
  <li class="Box Box8">8</li>
</ul>
```